# iPhone - voice recording in background

Tags: iphone, avaudiorecorder

I'm using AVAudioRecorder and able to record voice of the user.
But how can I countinue recording the voice when the app goes to background also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, it is allowed, you should set the key `UIBackgroundModes`'s value to `audio` in the application's `Info.plist` file.

Comment: for these there is no need sample code, you can implement the `AVAudioRecorder` in the standard way, and for the background recording you just add this extra row to your project's `Info.plist` file.

Comment: @Satyamsvv, i have same issues, do you got it resolved? And appreciate if you can send me some sample code.